# Platform independent paths in Java

Tags: java, file, cross-platform

I know the relative path of a file and want to handle it as a `File` object on both Linux and Windows.

What is the best way to specify platform-independent paths in Java?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The [`File`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html) class contains the following public members that you can use for platform specific file paths:

> `static String pathSeparator`:
>      The system-dependent path-separator character, represented as a string for convenience.
>   `static char    pathSeparatorChar`:
>      The system-dependent path-separator character.
>   `static String  separator`:
>       The system-dependent default name-separator character, represented as a string for convenience.
>   `static char    separatorChar`:
>       The system-dependent default name-separator character.

Comment: I tried using `pathSeparator` in my application, but on OS X, that's a colon (`:`). If you toss that into a file path, OS X will interpret it as a forward slash character within the folder name. ex: Instead of creating a folder named `foo` on the user's desktop, I accidentally created a folder literally named `Desktop/foo` in the user's *home* folder. Using a plain forward slash (`/`) works exactly as expected, however.

Comment: This answer requires a better explanation. `pathSeparator` and `pathSeparatorChar` refer to the separator used in the system's `PATH` variable. The question is referring to file paths, not the `PATH` variable. Thus, `separator` and `separatorChar` should be used.

Answer (score 133):

Just use `/`. I've been using it for 23.5 years. Never a problem.

Comment: @ses that's what the answer is about too. I have no idea what your first sentence is supposed to mean.

Comment: If I am searching for a file in /opt/template using java, is this equivalent to c://opt/template in windows?

Comment: Would work until some new OS doesn't come up with new exotic path separator! Maybe even then it would work, if JVM can handle "/" to that specific OS path separator conversion! So, generally "/" is a safe choice, but using explicit path separator is future fool proofing.

Comment: @Mohnish It would still work because Java would substitute, just like it does on Windows.

Comment: @AechoLiu That's just another SO answer. No more authoritative than this in, which is at least evidence-based. A proper citation would be from the JLS or JVM Specification or the Javadoc.

Comment: @EJP Sorry, I read the `Update` and saw the words `Now, I'm sure I've seen it documented` in that SO answer. So I believe it should be true. I encounter this problem today and found answers in SO. And you and that SO answer help me to solve that problem. I just don't want any downvotes in this anser, beacause I know you are right.

Comment: You can use `/` only in specific cases. If you need to compare different paths then you might need to convert the different separators to an unified one, in order to get the correct results. For example: `Paths.get("a/b").equals(Paths.get("a\\b"))` yields `false` result (same with compareTo method, doesn't return 0), meanwhile the following: `Paths.get("a/b").equals(Paths.get("a/b"))` returns `true`. Given this example, I strongly discourage the only use of `/` separator, since it might unexpectedly break your code interoperability between platforms.

Comment: Other Path class methods uses the platform separator, so here: `Paths.get("a/b").resolve("c")` on Windows, will result in `a/b\c' which will work with File opening, and other use-cases, but in equality testing, still could result in unexpected bugs.

Comment: @Spika The point is that `/` *is* the 'unified one'. Not a 'specific case'.

Answer (score 19):

You can use any path separator in Java, it will work on both Unix and Windows.
If you still want to use the system path separator there is the [`File.separator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#separator) property which will give you the right one depending on the *current* system.

For the root, you can use [`listRoots()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listRoots--) which gives you an array of root, there will be only one element on Unix systems, and as many as you have drives on Windows.

Comment: pathSeparator will retrieve the platform specific separator between paths ( ';' for unix ':' for windows). I think separator is more appropriate in this case.

Comment: pathSeparator is the separator for different entries in the PATH environment variable. For the question, File.separator would be the correct choice.

Comment: "You can use any path separator in Java, it will work on both Unix and Windows." -- wrong. If you use backslash (\) on Unix, it will not be recognized as a file path separator, it will be interpreted as a file name (Unix file names are allowed to contain backslashes).

Comment: @ColinHebert The answer isn't right as long as it talks about path separators.

Answer (score 12):

You can use the static field `File.separator` to retrieve the platform specific separator character for file paths

Answer (score 5):

Java is pretty smart about paths in File objects. I just use something like "../foo/bar" and it works in those two platforms plus MacOSX.

Answer (score 5):

java 7 also supports the use of [`Paths`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html) here

> The Path is obtained by invoking the getPath method of the default FileSystem.

You then may get a file from it by calling:

```
File fileSystemObtainedFile = Paths.get("C:\\foo\\bar.txt").toFile();
```

Answer (score 3):

Only 10 years too late....
The "It doesn't matter just use '/'" is only half true (ok, three quarters).  You have to think about where your data is coming from.

If you get a path in Java, it will use '/'
If you create a path in Java it will understand '/'

But what about paths that are input to your program?

Suppose I have a series of scripts that create a config (Properties) file.  Suppose one of the config variables is INTERESTING_FILE, and we generate this to be a filename including path.  Now suppose I want to extract the actual Filename from that, so I say

```
String[] filename = INTERESTING_FILE.split("/");
```

This will misbehave on Windows Systems, however

```
String[] filename = INTERESTING_FILE.split(pathSeparator);
```

will work (as will washing it through the Paths class).

I guess the point is, I wouldn't assume '/' is going to work in every case.

Comment: Doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: @NotAJavaGuy suggests that using "/" might be a problem because then you couldn't use "split" to find the filename. I would say that using "split" is the problem here. The better approach would be ```new File(filename).getName()```

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I like to use the Path class from Eclipse for handling paths in general, which you can just use standalone with few modifications as it's quite isolated.

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/eclipse.org/3.5/org.eclipse.equinox/common/3.5.0/org/eclipse/core/runtime/Path.java/?v=source