# Java Cross-Platform OS detection to declare file path location

Tags: java

I currently comprise the following code which fails to compile.  The `else if` statement reports that '`;' expected`. I don't understand why I can't use a `else if` for this scenario?

```
public class FileConfiguration {

    private String checkOs() {
        String path = "";        
        if (System.getProperty("os.name").startsWith("Windows")) {
            // includes: Windows 2000,  Windows 95, Windows 98, Windows NT, Windows Vista, Windows XP
            path = "C://Users//...";            

        }
        elseif (System.getProperty("os.name").startsWith("Mac")) {
            path = "///Users//...";
        }
        return path;        

    }

    // declare paths for file source and destination 
    String destinationPath = path;
    String sourcePath = path;
```

Comment: Looking from a C# point of view, you need a space between `elseif` unless its just a typo :)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548775/platform-independent-paths-in-java

Comment: Been programming in PHP recently.  Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It would be better if you were to use `user.name` and `user.home`. You can also get the separator using `file.separator`. [Check this out](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html). Those properties will really help you do this more cleanly without checking the OS.

Then there's also the matter of you needing to change to using `else if`, not `elseif`...

Answer (score 2):

**elseif** does not exist in java. You must use **else if** as:

```
if (a) {
// code
} else if (b) {
// code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no `elseif` keyword in java.
You should say `else if` (pay attention on the space)