# Directory indicator on windows and on Linux. 

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Platform independent paths in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548775/platform-independent-paths-in-java)

I make a program but it save some files in a directory that the user selects.

I need to make this program to work both in linux and windows , so for example on windows the directory seperator is `\` and on linux is `/` ...

How can I import one value that represents both depending the operating system?

Comment: Have you tried using `/` on windows to see what happens? ;)

Comment: Not currently I am using my code on linux. And I take an error. With the \ so probably with the / works! But I want to be sure for both situations.

Comment: `/` works on all platforms AFAIK.  You only need the platform specific separator when you are exporting this path to a non-Java program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File class offers you [system dependent separators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#pathSeparator)
its as easy as

path = "images" + File.separatorChar + "cat.jpg"

Answer (score 1):

If you want this, then you have to use

```
File.separator
```

This is a static field of File class of io package. For this purpose File has also some more static fields, like

```
pathSeparatorChar
pathSeparator
separatorChar
```

NOTE: The field names ended with Char are char typed and others are String typed just for the convinience.

Answer (score 1):

```
char separatorChar = java.io.File.separatorChar

String separator = System.getProperty("file.separator");
```

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#separator

Answer (score 0):

You can always use forward slashes. Windows supports them internally.