# How to load files on multiple platforms properly using Java?

Tags: java, path, filepath

I have a java swing database application which needs to be run on Windows and Linux. My database connection details are stored in a XML file and I load them.

This application can load this properties on Linux properly but it is not working on Windows.

How do I load files on multiple platforms properly using Java?

---

This is the code:

```
PropertyHandler propertyWriter = new PropertyHandler();

List keys = new ArrayList();
keys.add("ip");
keys.add("database");
Map localProps = propertyWriter.read(keys, "conf" + File.separatorChar + "properties.xml", true);//if false load from the local properties

//get properties from the xml in the internal package
List seKeys = new ArrayList();
seKeys.add("driver");
seKeys.add("username");
seKeys.add("password");

Map seProps = propertyWriter.read(seKeys, "conf" + File.separatorChar + "properties.xml", true);

String dsn = "jdbc:mysql://" + (String) localProps.get("ip") + ":3306/" + (String) localProps.get("database");
jDBCConnectionPool = new JDBCConnectionPool((String) seProps.get("driver"), dsn, (String) seProps.get("username"), (String) seProps.get("password"));
```

File reader method:

```
public Map read(List properties, String path, boolean isConfFromClassPath)
{
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    Map props = new HashMap();
    try {

        if (isConfFromClassPath) {
            InputStream in = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(path);
            prop.loadFromXML(in);

            for (Iterator i = properties.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
                String key = (String) i.next();
                props.put(key, prop.getProperty(key));
            }
            in.close();

        } else {
            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(path);
            prop.loadFromXML(in);

            for (Iterator i = properties.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
                String key = (String) i.next();
                props.put(key, prop.getProperty(key));
            }
            in.close();
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return props;
}
```

Comment: Usually you can go with the `/`, this works in most cases: `"conf/properties.xml"` (even on Windows).

Comment: Define 'not working properly'.

Comment: Is there any exception or backtrace from your code?

Comment: @AbdullahJibaly It works in *all* cases. I never use backslash in filenames.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Platform independent paths in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3548775/608639)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the file is in a jar file and accessed by the classpath then you should always use `/`.

The JavaDocs for the `ClassLoader.getResource` say that "The name of a resource is a '/'-separated path name that identifies the resource."

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there is *the* proper way, but one way is:

```
File confDir = new File("conf");
File propFile = new File(confDir, "properties.xml");
```

But in a scenario as simple as yours, I would just use `/`

Comment: Not what I would have recommended, but still a nice and creative workaround. :)

Comment: I would not recommend this approach for this scenario as well, but there are others, for instance reading multiple files in a directory that was passed as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a resource located in classpath, we can load it with following snippet:

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(
    "/META-INF/SqlQueryFile.sql")));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can load all files on multiple platforms without any trouble.

Kindly use Matcher.quoteReplacement(File.separator) for replacing the slash.

It will works for every platform.

```
String fileLocation = "/src/service/files";

fileLocation  = fileLocation.replaceAll("/",Matcher.quoteReplacement(File.separator));
```

Answer (score -1):

assuming that your file is in conf/properties.xml on Linux and conf\properties.xml on Windows,
use File.pathSeparator instead of File.separator

Comment: Why? Path separators are used to to separate different paths (the colon in Unix or semi-colon in Windows).

Comment: Noup, it is not working here I am getting an error when reading the file.

Comment: That's incorrect. pathSeparator is ";" or ":".

Comment: Yup, you're correct - got it backwards :-(