# Fix Hardcoded Windows Paths in Java so that it works in linux also

Tags: java, linux, operating-system

I have a java file that has some hard-coded path something like:

```java
public class ReportBuilder
{
  private static final String DIRECTORY = "META-INF";
  private static final String REPORT_HTML = "report.html";

  public static void createHTMLReport(String projectPath, String artifactName, ValidationResult result) throws MojoExecutionException {
    String directoryPath = projectPath + "\\" + "META-INF";
    String filePath = directoryPath + "\\" + "report.html";
  }
}
```

Linux its creating `META-INF` with a `\` and that is causing the build to fail.

How can I switch this to OS independent so that when the same is run on Linux it creates `META-INF` with correct path?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Platform independent paths in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3548775/608639), [How to load files on multiple platforms properly using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10594316/608639), [File path names for Windows and Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20979625/608639), [Difference between File.separator and slash in paths](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2417485/608639), etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of hardcoding separator `\` or `/`, use `File.separator`

```
String filePath = directoryPath + File.separator + "report.html";
```

or event better do not use path literals at all but create `Path` object like

```
Path filePath = Paths.get(directoryPath, "report.html");
```

such `Path` object you can pass to the `File` constructor/utils but also you can always take String value of the path by calling `toString()` on the instance