# How to treat the path of a file to the different operating systems in Java?

Tags: java

I need to implement portable code, but I do not know how to deal with different path conventions on different operating systems.

Comment: have you already seen this Q/A: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548775/platform-independent-paths-in-java][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548775/platform-independent-paths-in-java

Comment: Ricardo, do you mean the code runs on both unix and windows, or that you need to have the program on one machine navigate the path on another machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. Using the File class, if you pass the a given path like so:

`new File("myPathInUnixOrWindows");`

You will get a system independent file path. Make sure you import:

`import java.io.File;`

if you just want the abstract base of the path pass it an empty string:

`new File("");`

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: this is old documentation. Please provide good guidance and post at least the documentation to Java 6 or 7.

Comment: This only helps when you are dealing with paths to files on this computer.  I think the OP is asking about (for example) running an application on Windows that deals with UNIX pathnames.  The `File` API doesn't help in that case.

Comment: Still doesn't help.  How do I get `File` on a UNIX machine to generate pathname strings in Windows syntax?  The problem is that the `File` API largely assumes that you are dealing with pathnames for >>this<< computer.

Comment: ok, but he is asking for portable code, why would i need to know for anything else than "this" machine?

Comment: He asks *"How to treat the path of a file to the **different** operating systems in Java?"*.  Now, we can't be sure, but >>I<< think this means manipulating file paths on one system that may have come from ... and need to go back to ... a different system.

Comment: not trying to troll you, (i'm going to ask the OP maybe he will respond), but what would be a good use case for that? I cant think of any, thats why im askin :)

Answer (score -1):

```
new StringBuilder(dir)
    .append(File.pathSeparatorChar)
    .append(filename)
    .toString()
```