# How can I save a file with a generic file path for Windows, Mac and Linux?

Tags: java

I have an aplicattion that needs to create a folder to unzip some files, but I want to pass a file path that my application could run, create and save my files in any OS, but I don't know what should be the output Path to do that.

for example:

```
File folder = new File(outputFolder);
if (!folder.exists()) {
    folder.mkdir();
}
```

What path should I use in outputFolder to create my folder in Documents/UnzipTest in any Operation System (Windows, mac or linux)?

Comment: Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3548818/645270) answer, and the one below. It should help. (I think the one below is more helpful)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
System.getProperty("user.dir");
```

Or if you're using Java 7

```
Filesystems.getDefault();
```

will give you the base directory from which to work.

Answer (score 2):

Use [java.io.File#separator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/File.html#separator) :

```
String userHome = System.getProperty("user.home");
String outputFolder = userHome + File.separator + "dir1";
File folder = new File(outputFolder);
if (!folder.exists()) {
   folder.mkdir();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would define a property (in some external properties file, for example) for the *root* folder, so user can define what is the root folder after the setup or during the installation for all your operations.

Other option is to use *user folder* (aka *home folder*) as this root folder (or if above property is not defined), defined in system property `user.dir`. Or use folder where your application is installed - you can find it e.g. by finding some resource in application jar and then parsing path from returned URL.

With root folder defined, you can use constructor `new File(rootFolder, outputFolder)`; where you can simply use slashes for the path in `outputFolder` (e.g. /foo/bar). Such path would work for all OSes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/) from [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/) with the classes [`FileUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) and [`FilenameUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html).

If you use in your application the UNIX style for your paths, you can transform the path to SO style with the method:

```
org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils.separatorsToSystem(String)
```

If you want create a directory only if not exists:

```
org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.forceMkdir(File)
```

May you have a path to the directory and may you need a new folder in this directory, you can cancatenate using the method for get the full path:

```
org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils.concat(String, String)
```

The path returned path is always normalized, contain separators in the format of the system.

May you need the user directory path:

```
org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.getUserDirectory()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String outputFolder = System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator + "Documents" + File.separator +"TestandoUnzip";
```

The code that I needed. Thanks guys.