# Proper place for saving file in User's PC or Server

Tags: java, linux, windows, file, io

In my Java app, I generate `pdf` and save it to a location on user's PC e.g. `C:\\Download`. However, as various users have different operating systems e.g. `Windows` or `Linux`, I think it is good idea to save the generated `pdf` file to a generic place for all of the operating system. For this situation, should I save it:

**1.** A generic user directory in the operating system?

**2.** A fix place e.g. `C:\\Download`. But in this scene, user may not have write permission in a Company domain.

Or any proper place that is suitable for `Linux` and `Windows`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14552217/how-can-i-save-a-file-with-a-generic-file-path-for-windows-mac-and-linux  have you checked this?

Comment: In general, you should _let the user select_, usually by using a command-line parameter.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- Thanks a lot, but sometimes user does not have enough knowledge and it is good idea to set it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid any operating system dependencies use the "user.home" property in java :

```
pdfDirectory = new File (System.getProperty("user.home"),"pdfDir");
```

- Generic user directory for all operating systems ✅
- Current user has access to his home directory ✅