# How to set Gradle `options.bootClasspath` in an os independent manner?

Tags: java, groovy, gradle

Because my Java sources and targets must be JRE 1.6 compatible, I need to set `options.bootClasspath` to a path that contains the 1.6 versions of `rt.jar` and `jce.jar`. It must build on both Windows and Unix (Linux/Solaris). What is the proper way to do this? I now use the following approach in my top-level `build.gradle`, it works, but it seems far from elegant, especially the os-dependent separator `:` or `;`:

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os

subprojects {
  apply plugin: 'java'

  compileJava {
    sourceCompatibility = 1.6
    targetCompatibility = 1.6
    def java6_home = System.getenv("JAVA_HOME_6")
    def java6_lib = "C:/localdata/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.6.0_45/jre/lib/"

    if (java6_home != null) {
      java6_lib = java6_home + "/jre/lib/"
    }

    def sep = ':'
    if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
      sep = ';'
    }
    options.bootClasspath = java6_lib + "rt.jar" + sep + java6_lib + "jce.jar"
  }
}
```

Comment: There is `separator` and `pathSeparator` in `File` as referenced in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548775/platform-independent-paths-in-java). That should ease some of your elegance concerns.

Comment: Thanx, using `File.pathSeparator` saves 5 lines of code :-)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I am using the following code (assuming the JDK6_HOME points to the root of the JDK 1.6 installation):

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    doFirst {
        if (sourceCompatibility == '1.6' && System.env.JDK6_HOME != null) {
            options.fork = true
            options.bootClasspath = "$System.env.JDK6_HOME/jre/lib/rt.jar"
            options.bootClasspath += "$File.pathSeparator$System.env.JDK6_HOME/jre/lib/jsse.jar"
            // use the line above as an example to add jce.jar 
            // and other specific JDK jars
        }
    }
}
```

This approach automatically detects the presence of the environment variable and automatically sets the `bootClasspath` for all modules that declare `sourceCompatibility` as 1.6.

The `options.fork = true` is required when you use `bootClasspath`.

Comment: Thanx! Using File.pathSeparator saves 5 lines of code. However, I doubt if the `options.fork = true` is needed. The user guide says: "By default, the Java compiler runs in the Gradle process. Setting options.fork to true causes compilation
to occur in a separate process. In the case of the Ant javac task, this means that a new process will be forked for
each compile task, which can slow down compilation."

Comment: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.CompileOptions.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.CompileOptions:bootClasspath : Only takes effect if fork is true.

Comment: Thanx for giving the proper ref. So I guess there is no way to work around the resulting compilation slowdown :-(

Comment: The documentation has changed since 2.6 because it does not mention to take effect only with `fork = true` anymore. See [Gradle 2.5 Documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/2.5/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.CompileOptions.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.CompileOptions:bootClasspath) vs [Gradle 2.6 Documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/2.6/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.CompileOptions.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.CompileOptions:bootClasspath). Did not try it yet but will do and will report findings.

Comment: I can confirm that `fork=true` is not needed on Gradle 2.10. I'm using JDK8 and setting JDK7's `rt.jar` to prevent "bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.7" and the warning disappeared even without `fork`.

Comment: I newer versions of gradle the way the bootstrap classpath is set changed: options.bootstrapClasspath = files("$System.env.JDK7_HOME/jre/lib/rt.jar", "..")

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer can work, but if you're using some classes outside java.lang (e.g. `javax.crypto.*`) you may find you'll get various ClassNotFoundExceptionException's being raised as more JAR files need to be added to the bootClasspath.

To avoid this, I use the following which has the following advantages;

- The options are only set if required
- All the JAR files are added to the bootClasspath
- The extensionDirs is also set (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#extdirs-option)

.

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    doFirst {
        if (JavaVersion.toVersion(sourceCompatibility) == JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
            && JavaVersion.current() != JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
            && System.env.JDK6_HOME != null) {
            options.fork = true
            options.bootClasspath = fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: "$System.env.JDK6_HOME/jre/lib/").join(File.pathSeparator)
            options.extensionDirs = "$System.env.JDK6_HOME/jre/lib/ext/"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Gradle 4.3 you can use [`CompileOptions.bootstrapClasspath`](https://docs.gradle.org/4.3/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/compile/CompileOptions.html#getBootstrapClasspath()) instead to remove the need for an OS-dependent separator.

Answer (score 0):

A slight modification of the cool solution by Oleg Estekhin above, but doesn't require JDKX_HOME to be set (calculates it on the fly.)  Also, modified for doing Java 1.7 builds:

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    doFirst {
        if (sourceCompatibility == '1.7') {
            def JDK7_HOME = "/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7".execute().text.trim()
            options.bootClasspath = "$JDK7_HOME/jre/lib/rt.jar"
            options.bootClasspath += "$File.pathSeparator$JDK7_HOME/jre/lib/jsse.jar"
            // use the line above as an example to add jce.jar 
            // and other specific JDK jars
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The platform independence of `$File.pathSeparator` is lost when you use `/usr/libexec/java_home` to detect the java home.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to add many jars to my bootClassPath using the instructions above, but never resolved my build issue.  I finally resolved the build by setting my JAVA_HOME to point to the IBM JDK 1.7 required by the WebSphere server and adding it to my path.  My other projects require Oracle JDK 1.8 so I did not want to make this change permanent.

```
set JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\java_1.7.1_64\"
set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%
gradle clean war
gradle clean ear deployLocal
```