# How do i make this File I/O Java program run in Unix?

Tags: java, unix, file-io

Below is the program that prints all the files & folders from the given path.

```
import java.io.File;

public class ListDirectoryRecursive{

    public static void listRecursive(File dir){
        if(dir.isDirectory()){
            File[] items = dir.listFiles();
            for(File item : items){
                System.out.println(item.getAbsoluteFile());
                if(item.isDirectory()){
                    listRecursive(item);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        /* Unix path is: /usr/home/david/workspace/JavaCode */
        File dir = new File("C:\\Users\\david\\workspace\\JavaCode");
        listRecursive(dir);
    }
}
```

How do i make this java program run on Unix? What is the standard approach to make this program portable?

Edit: I guess, we know on any OS, user home directory is part of the environment setting with values like "c:\users\david" in windows and "/user/home/david" in Unix.

Comment: You dont have to explicitely say c:\, you could just type /Users/david/workspace/JavaCode and can use it on both the platform.

Comment: System.getProperty("user.home");

Comment: @almasshaikh: ...assuming `/Users/david` were valid on UNIX (it may not be).

Comment: I always use the `/` for path separators *irrespective* of platform in Java (works on Win and Unix). Pass a different path in Windows from Unix as a platform specific variable. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3548775/3651800

Comment: I agree @nneonneo I believe that's what OP is after?

Comment: @almasshaikh: OP actually says "Unix path is: /usr/home/david/workspace/JavaCode" in the comments. So he does not want `/Users` on UNIX.

Comment: @nneonneo This program could be part of an application, so please do not consider reading command line arguments, please read my comment below.

Comment: @overexchange: Then you have to be more specific as to what directories you are accessing. Accessing the root directory is different from accessing a user directory, is different from accessing a temporary directory, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Take the directory as an argument via `args`:

```
File dir = new File(args[1]);
```

(checking of course that `args.length` is sufficient).

Then you can simply do

```
java ListDirectoryRecursive C:\Users\david\workspace\JavaCode
```

on Windows, and

```
java ListDirectoryRecursive ~david/workspace/JavaCode
```

on UNIX. This has the distinct advantage of allowing you use this program to list any directory, rather than being a hardcoded path.

Answer (score 1):

Make the hardcoded absolute path `C:\\Users\\david\\workspace\\JavaCode` relative.

Answer (score 1):

please dont harcode

```
File dir = new File("C:\\Users\\david\\workspace\\JavaCode");
```

use `System.getProperty("user.home");` to get `/usr/home/david` or  `C:\Users\david\` directory
like

```
String path = System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator + "workspace" + File.separator + "JavaCode";
File dir = new File(path);
```

thanks overexchange

Comment: `System.getProperty()` answers half of the question, Can we use, any of these 4 properties `File.separator` / `File.pathSeparator` /  `File.separatorChar` / `File.pathSeparatorChar` to define separators? If yes, How do i use it?

Comment: `String path = System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator + "workspace" + File.separator + "JavaCode";`