# how programmatically distinguish between Unix and Windows directory

Tags: java

In a java method i am loading a path name into a string variable, not knowing whether it is a Unix or a Windows path name.

How can i programmatically check whether it is a Unix or a Windows path?

```
   if path.contains(":") execute a Windows-related function
   else execute a Unix-related function
```

won't work, because Unix path names can contain a ":" as far as i know. Same with "/" for Unix , because Windows path names can contain a "/" .
So how could i do this best?

**EDIT:** I am loading directory names for remote machines, so i doubt i can use Use System.getProperty("os.name").

i was thinking about using Regex, but since i have no idea about regex in Java i have not considered that yet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Platform independent paths in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548775/platform-independent-paths-in-java)

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you need to know whether the path is a Windows or a Linux path?

Comment: i need to know it, because i will create a custom xml structure with according tags, depending on whether it is a Windows on a Linux system.

Comment: Well, can't the remote machines add that information to the file?

Comment: no, the remote machines wont have access to this xml structure

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, using path names to determine OS platform is not the best idea.

Use System.getProperty("os.name")

and have a look here:
[How do I programmatically determine operating system in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228477/how-do-i-programmatically-determine-operating-system-in-java)

Comment: The OP was asking how to tell if a given file path was Unix or Windows, not necessarily what platform the program is executing on.

Comment: But in fact, the real need, as described by later post of Sandra is: "i will create a custom xml structure with according tags, depending on whether it is a Windows on a Linux system".