# Groovy split path into name and parent

Tags: groovy, path

I am trying to split a path into parent and the name.

When trying

```
String path = "/root/file"
File file = new File(path)

println("Name: " + file.name)
println("Parent: " + file.parent)
```

We get

```
Name: file
Parent: /root
```

With the Windows path `C:\\root\\file.exe` we get

```
Name: C:\root\file.exe
Parent: null
```

Is this the intended behaviour? And if it is how do I get the same result for a Windows path? (If possible please without using regular expressions)

Comment: This answer for Java (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548775/platform-independent-paths-in-java) should work for Groovy too.

Answer (score 2):

use .replace to change the "\" to "/

```
String path = "C:\\root\\file.exe"
path = path.replace("\\","/")
File file = new File(path)

println("Name: " + file.name)
println("Parent: " + file.parent)
```