# File path issue on windows vs Unix in java

Tags: java, platform-independent

In my program, I am reading a resource file for a unit test. I use file path as:

```
\\\path\\\to\\\file
```

On my machine(Windows) this runs fine. But on server(Unix), this fails, and I have to change it to: `/path/to/file`

But Java is supposed to be platform independent. So isn't this behaviour unexpected?

Comment: Related post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548775/platform-independent-paths-in-java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `FileSystem.getSeparator()` or `System.getProperty("file.separator")` instead of using slashes.

EDIT:
You can get an instance of `FileSystem` via `FileSystems.getDefault` (JDK 1.7+)

Comment: You might want to clarify how to acquire a `FileSystem` instance

Answer (score 3):

You can use `File.separator` to get the appropriate character in a platform-independent way.

Answer (score 1):

Java is platform independent. The file path-es and some system calls are not.

As long as the path is relative, you can use `File.separator`:

```
    String path = "path" + File.separator + "to" + File.separator + "file";
    System.out.println(path); // prints path\to\file on windows
```

Sometimes it's an option is to provide a Properties file and let the user define path of that actual file. This way full paths are okay too. You can read the properties like this:

```
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.load(new FileInputStream(filePath));
```

The next question is: how to specify the location of that file? That might be either a file on a relative path. If that's not viable for your app, then you can let the user specify it in a system property:

```
java ... -DconfigFile=C:\TEMP\asd.txt .... -jar myapp.jar
```

Then you can access it like this:

```
// prints C:\TEMP\asd.txt if you specified -DconfigFile=C:\TEMP\asd.txt
System.out.println(System.getProperty("configFile"));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behaviour.

Java **code** *compiles* on any machine/OS provided you have the right version of Java installed on it.

However, at run time, your code sees only a variable **value** like another one, which happens to be `\path\to\file`

When it talks to the file system, it uses that particular value ; the file system then tries to find that path you've given to it ; which is why one syntax works fine on Windows but will not work on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Better way of doing this is :

```
val pathUri = Paths.get(".//src//test//res//file.txt").toUri()
val is = FileInputStream((File(pathUri)))
```