# How to get file's icon and type description in Ubuntu?

Tags: java, swing, icons

With Java 11 on Windows, I can get info about my files using:

```
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileSystemView

var type = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getSystemTypeDescription(file)
var icon = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getSystemIcon(file)
```

On Ubuntu (20.04) however, things are different. By now, I've figured out that the icon has a `ToolkitImage` inside instead of a `BufferedImage`, which is annoying because it's internal API, but I can render that now.

The remaining problem is the file type, which still returns `null` on Ubuntu when using the `FileSystemView`, or returns "Generic File" for every file if using the `new FileChooser().getTypeDescription(file)` way.

How can I get a proper file type description on Ubuntu?

Comment: If this truly isn't working, I think your best bet would be to go to Oracle's Java support pages and ask for this to be fixed. It's right there in the API and it *should work* as you'd expect

Comment: I found this: `fc.getUI().getFileView(fc).getIcon(file);` on this page. Try this. If it works, close your own question with this q/a? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4363251/how-do-i-get-a-files-icon-in-java

Comment: That code gives me the same result on both platforms: Icon on Windows and `null` on Ubuntu.

Comment: @Jorn As you can see in the [`FileSystemView` class `getSystemTypeDescription` method source code](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/19fb8f93c59dfd791f62d41f332db9e306bc1422/src/java.desktop/share/classes/javax/swing/filechooser/FileSystemView.java#L207-L222), it relies on the OS native file chooser to obtain the required value. Are you using an Ubuntu version with graphical interface or not? If not, it may be very likely the cause of the problem.

Comment: sounds to me like this is not an issue with the FileSystemView but the file itself. unix and windows have different separators to define the path. check here for relative issues. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49410193/file-path-issue-on-windows-vs-unix-in-java

Comment: @jccampanero It's a standard Ubuntu 20.04 installation, window manager and all. In a VirtualBox VM in my case, but that shouldn't matter.

Comment: @derpdewp It's not a problem for one file. I've tried hundreds, and no it's not a path separator issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### `getFileSystemView` is broken

A bold claim: Whatever you wanted this to do, it won't work. Based on looking at the source. You can skip this section if you're willing to accept it's a dead end, but I best back up such a claim, so read on if you'd like to be convinced:

The sources I have here for both JDK11 and JDK17 do the following relatively simplistic approach for `FileSystemView.getFileSystemView()`:

1. If the value of `File.separator` is `\\`, return the windows implementation.
2. If the value is `/`, return the unix implementation (that'd therefore be just about everything else, notably including macs).
3. Otherwise return the generic implementation. Let's forget about this, which OS has neither `/` or `\\` at this point? pre-MacOSX mac os is long dead at this point, that's the only one I can think of.

The unix implementation is:

`return null;`

Oof. That's not going to get us very far. The windows implementation goes with ShellFolder. Which is general code; I do not understand why the unix implementation just disregards it.

Perhaps this explanation makes the most sense: `.getSystemTypeDescription` is intended to return the opinion of the OS itself as to how one would describe the type of file this is. The reason the unix implementation just `return null;`s is simply that as a concept this isn't how unix works. The OS itself doesn't have some sort of registry that maps file extensions to names (such as windows' HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/.txt and friends), nor does it have a concept where each file has its own metadata that contains additional info, such as 'which app created me' / 'which app should be used to open me when double clicked', such as MacOSX does. (Of course, if you do run this on a mac, you still get `null`, which really isn't excusable).

Of course, we now get into a more tricky debate: What is your OS, really. One could say 'well, its linux, and KDE, or GnomeDesktop or whatnot, well, that's just this app, you know'. But one could also say that you run the java app on the OS 'KDE/Linux'. In other words, what does `System` mean when we talk about `FileSystemView`. Evidently, the JDK impl source I'm looking at (which is OpenJDKs) chooses to define it as 'just linux', which has no such thing as the 'system's opinion on what type of file this is', making `return null;` a correct, but mostly useless, answer.

The `getSystemIcon` implementation of the abstract supertype itself is weird: It is a near carbon copy of the windows-specific implementation of getSystemTypeDescription - namely: Get the `ShellFolder` object, then ask it. I have no idea why on unix, 'just ask the shellfolder' is the implementation of `getSystemIcon`, whereas 'just return null' is the implementation of `getSystemTypeDescription` - why not also ask the shellfolder?

At any rate, even if you did, not much use there: The default shell folder implementation *always* returns `null`. This is `sun.awt` code so it is considerably more likely that the implementation of AWT for that specific platform overrides it, but this isn't in the openjdk sources as far as I looked, at any rate.

The default impl of `getSystemIcon` will return either a generic file icon or a generic folder icon (by invoking `UIManager.getIcon("FileView.directotyIcon")`, for example) if the ShellFolder returns `null` as an icon.

So let's give up on this implementation: Conclude it cannot help you.

### Define 'type description'

What does that really mean? I can only foresee 3 useful takes on what this is supposed to mean:

- Something that human eyeballs and brains will likely understand.
- A mime type, which is a universal standard for describing file types.
- "Whatever the window manager that the user is using would see in the local equivalent of a file explorer app - `explorer.exe`, on windows, `Finder.app` on mac, etc".

Presumably the `getSystemTypeDescription` is the method that is supposed to answer the 3rd option (the local window manager's description). But, given that OpenJDK doesn't actually implement this (well, it does, in a useless way, by just returning null), the only way you're getting that is if you put in the considerable effort to figure out how each and every popular window manager used worldwide does it and port it all over to java code. I assume you're not interested in doing that kind of work.

But the other 2 - there are ways to get that.

Let's start with mime types.

Plan A is to ask java:

```
import java.nio.file.*;

class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    var p = Paths.get("test.otf");
    Files.createFile(p);
    System.out.println(Files.probeContentType(p));
    Files.delete(p);
  }
}
```

Save to that a file and run it: `java Test.java` (yay JDK11+ where you can just pass java files to the JVM executable), and see if it works. That is, that should be returning `application/font-sfnt` for you. It does, for me at any rate, with Coretto JDK17 (`java -version`: `openjdk version "17.0.3" 2022-04-19 LTS`) on Ubuntu 20.04.1.

Running it with Temurin 17 (JDK from the Adoptium project) on mac: `font/otf`. Oh well, that's embarrassing, perhaps. But it's not necessarily a bad answer. Unfortunately, the Mac's own Finder app has a 'type description' column and that's "OpenType® font", not "font/otf". Presumably macs have a mimetype to human readable description database someplace that as far as I know you can't access with generic java code. Still, "font/otf" is better than "an .otf file", presumably.

If the probe method isn't working for you, you can always choose to check if `/etc/mime.types` exists, which should exist on linuxen. For each line, `.split("\\s+")`; `v[0]` is the mime type, and the remaining elements are each an extension without the dot, e.g. my ubuntu install would list `application/font-sfnt` as being the mime type for types `otf` and `ttf`.

Yet another alternative is to ship a known list of extension-to-mimetype mappings. For example, The Eclipse Jetty has a [`MimeTypes`](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-10.0.x/jetty-http/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/http/MimeTypes.java) class that is pre-filled with [this sizable list of known extensions](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-10.0.x/jetty-http/src/main/resources/org/eclipse/jetty/http/mime.properties).

### Steve Jobs / flash the MIME gang-sign

If you're like Steve or the MIME consortium, this whole business of treating 'the stuff after the last dot in the file name' as somehow indicative of what kind of file it is, leaves a bad taste in your mouth and you'd like to avoid it. You can, sort of. On unixen anyway. Most unix installs have `/usr/bin/file` - both my mac and the ubuntu install I'm looking at has this. You can `ProcessBuilder.exec` that. This tool does not look at the file name at all, solely at the actual content. It might be slow (reads the whole thing if it needs to), but, if I run it on an OTF file, it spits out:

```
actual-valid-font-file.tof: OpenType font data
```

which is certainly a string I could show to a user that's "prettier" than `font/otf`, though it isn't quite what a native mac app would show (which shows `OpenType® font` as mentioned before.

On windows, where `file` (the filetype guesser application) isn't usually available, well, it sounds like `FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getSystemTypeDescription(file)` actually works. I bet the number of systems where `/usr/bin/file` doesn't exist, *and* `getSystemTypeDescription` returns nothing useful, is infinitesemal.

### Icons

Presumably you want the same thing here: Give me that icon which would be familiar to the user, which runs into the same issue, especially on linux: Each and every 'file explorer' app has its own icon set, and there are **a lot** of file explorer apps - just about every window manager ships their own version of it and there are **a lot** of linux window managers. I'm not sure any JVM impl out there has code to fetch the right icon out of all of those different window manager implementations, and I don't think there's a standardized way to accomplish this using just plain jane disk access, either.

But, we've established you can pick up the mime type (if using `/usr/bin/file`, there's the `--mime-type` option. (My `/usr/bin/file` gives me `application/vnd.ms-opentype`, so that's 3 different mimetypes for the same thing already, boy that whole XKCD comic of 'there are 14 different standards' comes up a lot, doesn't it)

Given a mime type, there are loads of icon sets out there, free and open source.

The [Oxygen icons](https://github.com/pasnox/oxygen-icons-png/tree/master/oxygen/256x256/mimetypes) project is a FOSS iconset hosted on github with an icon (in various sizes) for a boatload of mimetypes. You could use `.getSystemIcon` first, and if that doesn't return a suitable answer (bit tricky; sometimes you get a generic 'its a file' icon which you might not want), then use an icon set. You won't be matching the Look-n-Feel of the platform, but then again if this question is really just "I want to write an app in swing that looks indistinguishable from the host OS, be it windows, mac, KDE, Gnome, Xfce, Cinnamon, Budgie, or Enlightenment", the only pragmatic answer pretty much has to be: "Just give up on that pipe dream".

NB: Hoi :)

Answer (score 0):

The code for `getSystemTypeDescription` is

```
public String getSystemTypeDescription(File f) {
        return null;
}
```

which is overridden in `WindowsFileSystemView`, but not in `UnixFileSystemView`. Maybe [JFileChooser](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#getTypeDescription-java.io.File-) suits your needs:

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
String type = chooser.getTypeDescription(file);
```

I get a FileNotFoundException during the execution of `getSystemIcon`. Following the code, in the method `getShellFolder` there is this snippet

```
if (!Files.exists(Paths.get(file.getPath()), LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS)) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException();
}
```

so symbolic links are not followed, and maybe that's the issue. But again, JFileChooser works:

```
Icon icon = chooser.getIcon(file);
```

Comment: I already tried the `FileChooser` route, as you can see in the comments on the question. It returns the same thing as the `FileSystemView` for `getIcon`, and it returns "Generic File" for all type descriptions. That's not helpful.

Comment: Please see updated question

Comment: @Jorn in no comment you nominated JFileChooser which, on my machine, gives different results than FileSystemView. Sorry, I can't test again now.