# Check if Dir exists in Windows/Unix using Java

Tags: java, linux, windows

Since Unix reads only '/' for folder structure and windows takes both '\' ,'/' .Is there a way to check if dir exists for both in Java?
if folder structure has '\' and we use --> 'f.isDirectory()'  , the Unix doesn't read the folder structure.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Platform independent paths in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548775/platform-independent-paths-in-java)

Comment: no,it doesnt really help, thanks anyways

Comment: "If the folder structure has \ ...". Well make sure it doesn't have \ before you try. For example by converting them.

Comment: @Kayaman - I am trying to unzip a file which has folders, files seperated with "\" , so it gets unzipped fine in windows and not in Unix

Comment: @Noobie zip files are platform agnostic. If you've managed to somehow create a problem with zip files due to the path separator, you're doing something more complicated than it needs to be, and wrong.

Comment: Could you post the code that you are having a problem with, otherwise it is hard to help you.

Comment: Very good question. I struggle with this my self. Please let me know if you found a solution.
Those who gives negative credit are not reading what you actually asked. It's simple and clear.

Answer (score 1):

You could look into using the [Path](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Path.html) API from `java.nio.file`:

```
Path rootDirectory = Path.of(System.getProperty("user.home")); // Let's say /home/noobie
Path subDirectory = rootDirectory.resolve("sub"); // home/noobie/sub
Path subSubDirectory = subDirectory.resolve("subsub"); // /home/noobie/sub/subsub
Path subSubDirectoryMethod2 = rootDirectory.resolve("sub").resolve("subsub"); // /home/noobie/sub/subsub
```

This API works regardless of platform. To check if a path is a directory you can do:

```
boolean isDir = Files.isDirectory(path);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this post, it mentions the difference between Linux and Windows and how to fix it with File.seperator

[File.separator or File.pathSeparator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971964/file-separator-or-file-pathseparator)